# Create Slack Channel for Bot User

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

I'm creating a web integration for my platform, using a bot user to "log" certain events.

I would like to have a new channel/group for each event type so they get shown in a list instead of all together in one channel. For this purpose I created a bot using the python Slacker integration.

Since the slack API refuses to let me create a channel as a bot user, I would need to use to the oauth2 API to create a channel and then let the bot write stuff in it. This means I need to authenticate as a user to slack with my platform.

This feels kind of hacky since the user I'd be using (probably my own) would be in the code just to create channels for the bot.

Is there a better way to do this? Whats best practice here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a better way.

If you use a Slack app for your app you will receive two new access tokens during installation. A bot access token and a general access token. Both will have the scopes you specified during installation, but the later will not be limited to the bot subset. Use the later to create the new channels.

You will need to go though to oauth process to install your app for your Slack team, but only once for installation. The tokens will remain valid and should of course be stored by your app.

Not sure how a familiar you are with Slack apps, but you do not need to publish your app to the Slack App directory. That is optional.

See the [official page](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button) about the Add-to-Slack button, section Add to Slack Flow.

Comment: I seem to have a major misunderstanding of the process:
1. I created a slack app. This gives me a private and a public key.
2. Not sure how to proceed, how do I install my own app for my own team? (I assume that gives me the api-key I can use in my backend)

Comment: Yes. In order to install your Slack app and get the access tokens for a specific team you need to have a custom website with the "Add to Slack button". The website needs to be able to run though the oath process with Slack in order to get the access token. See [docu](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button) for details

Comment: Thats weird to me, I only need to do this once (since the app is only for one team, which is managing the website), so there is now easier way to access that token than creating a website (page) im only using once?

Comment: there is another approach I used for some Of my apps. you can create a new slack user dedicated to be used for apps only. mine is called 'Slack Admin' and I use the token of that user for cases where I do not need to have a full blown Slack app.

Comment: but in any case I think its good practice to keep the access token in a config file and not put it in the code.